# logits and labels must be same size error using SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm totally new to Tensorflow. I've been trying to refashion the [Deep MNIST](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) tutorial to predict movie ratings on the MovieLens data set. I've simplified the model slightly so that instead of using a 5 point scale it's a simple binary Y / N rating (similar to the most recent rating system on Netflix). I am attempting to only use part ratings to predict preferences for new items. When training the model I get the following error in the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Eric/dev/Coding Academy >Tutorials/tf_impl/deep_tf_group_rec_SO.py", line 223, in <module>
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys, keep_prob: 0.5})
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site->packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1550, in run
    _run_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site->packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3764, in >_run_using_default_session
    session.run(operation, feed_dict)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site->packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site->packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site->packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site->packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: logits and >labels must be same size: logits_size=[1,2] labels_size=[50,2]
     [[Node: SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = >SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, >_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Reshape_2, Reshape_3)]]

Caused by op u'SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits', defined at:
  File "/Users/Eric/dev/Coding Academy >Tutorials/tf_impl/deep_tf_group_rec_SO.py", line 209, in <module>
    cross_entropy = >tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, >logits=y_conv))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site->packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1617, in >softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
    precise_logits, labels, name=name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site->packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 2265, in >_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
    features=features, labels=labels, name=name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site->packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in >apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site->packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2327, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site->packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1226, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): logits and labels must >be same size: logits_size=[1,2] labels_size=[50,2]
     [[Node: SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = >SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, >_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Reshape_2, Reshape_3)]]
```

Code causing the error can be viewed [here](http://gist.github.com/EricSEkong/eaa67da30390a4eb2d50c282f3a2e4c7)

Sizes of variables used in the model:

- x (?, 1682)
- y_ (?, 2)
- x_history (?, 290, 290, 1)
- h_pool1 (?, 145, 145, 32)
- h_pool2 (?, 73, 73, 64)
- h_pool3 (?, 37, 37, 128)
- h_pool4 (?, 19, 19, 256)
- h_pool5 (?, 10, 10, 512)
- h_fc1 (?, 1024)
- h_fc1_drop (?, 1024)
- y_conv (?, 2)

Comment: I've created a gist: https://gist.github.com/EricSEkong/eaa67da30390a4eb2d50c282f3a2e4c7

Comment: If it's a binary rating then why is the labels size 50x3?

Comment: Oh man! So dumb. I'll fix that and see. Thanks

Comment: @Aaron I've updated the code following your comments but now I'm getting a [1,2]vs[50,2] mismatch. I've updated the question and gist to reflect this.

Comment: The error message says that those two things should be the same size. You should look at your code and find out how come there is only one prediction instead of 50.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. I've been following up on your comment. Are the any common gottach that I should be looking out for?

Comment: You can try printing out the size of all your tensorflow variables and seeing if they are the size that you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is where you reshape your input batch (shape 50 training instances x 1682 features) to [-1, 290, 290, 1] in this line:

```
x_history = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 290, 290, 1])
```

You can see the shape x_history ends up with by running this:

```
x_history.eval(feed_dict={x:batch[0], y_:batch[1], keep_prob:1.0}).shape

=> (1, 290, 290, 1)
```

This is effectively taking all the features for your batch of 50 instances and putting it in a single instance (first dimension is 1 where it needs to be 50), then running that through the rest of the network.
So, your cross_entropy evaluation is failing because it can't line up the batch of 50 target labels with the single output of your network.

You need to choose layer shapes so that the batch dimension (the ? in your shape printouts) is preserved through the network.  One way to do this would be to pad out your features to 1764 and reshape to [-1,42,42,1], since 42*42 = 1764.

It's worth noting that 2d convolution is most commonly used with image data which is naturally 2 dimensional.  Given your features aren't 2 dimensional you may be better off starting with a simpler fully connected layer network?

Answer (score 0):

To get past this issue I ended up decreasing the batch size from 50 to one

```
batch = create_batches(train_data_pairs, 1)
```

and dramatically increasing the number of training iterations. Also, to accuracy I test the model against a large number of small slices of test data then take the mean of this evaluation.

This is more of a hack than a solution to the problem however, it let me move on to exploring other aspects of TensorFlow and play with the data in different ways.